# Rails devise sign in not working after sign out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, view, devise

When I open the web app, I can sign in via the following form:

```
<div class="flex flex-col items-center h-screen my-56">
  <div class="w-full max-w-xs ">
    <div class="px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4 bg-white rounded shadow-md">
      <div class="mb-4">
        <label class="block mb-2 text-sm font-bold text-gray-700" for="username">Email</label>
        <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
          <%= f.input :email,
                      required: false,
                      autofocus: true,
                      label: false,
                      input_html: { autocomplete: "email", class:"shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" } %>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-6">
        <label class="block mb-2 text-sm font-bold text-gray-700" for="username">Password</label>
          <%= f.input :password,
                    required: false,
                    label: false,
                    input_html: { autocomplete: "current-password", class:"shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" } %>
      </div>
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Login", class:"px-4 py-2 cursor-pointer font-bold text-white bg-blue-500 rounded hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" %>
        <% end %>
        <a class="inline-block text-sm font-bold text-blue-500 align-baseline hover:text-blue-800" href="#">Forgot Password</a>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

If I am to sign out and try to sign back in, the sign in button does not work. It behave as a button but when clicked it does nothing. Why is this?

Going to the same view...

```
    started GET "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2021-08-30 10:14:03 -0400 
    Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML 
        Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb   
        Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 10.8ms | Allocations: 7414)
        [Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date.
        Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 17.6ms | Allocations: 12591) Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 18.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 13330)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are going to the same view? What do you see in the console?

Comment: Yes it is going to the same view. ```tarted GET "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2021-08-30 10:14:03 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 10.8ms | Allocations: 7414)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. 
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 17.6ms | Allocations: 12591)
Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 18.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 13330)```